# Caliburn Micro View First Bootstrapper OnStartup for WPF application

Tags: c#, wpf, caliburn.micro

First of all this is my first contact with Caliburn.Micro, C# and WPF. I have gone through the Calibur.Micro tutorial and stopped in the moment of "[All about actions](https://caliburnmicro.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=All%20About%20Actions)" and First View subsection. Author wrote the solution for Silverlight application as follow:

```
public class MefBootstrapper : BootstrapperBase
{
    //same as before

    protected override void OnStartup(object sender, StartupEventArgs e)
    {
        Application.RootVisual = new ShellView();
    }

    //same as before
 }
```

So this is solution how to say bootstrapper which view use as base to show. About WPF I get only enigmatic information:

> In this scenario, we simply override OnStartup, instantiate the view
>   ourselves and set it as the RootVisual (or call Show in the case of
>   WPF).

So the Silverlight example is very clear for me, we just manually instantiate the proper View to property `Application.RootVisual`. But is for me totally unclear what is the Show method, which member it is. How to call it.

Thanks for help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Caliburn.Micro provides a [BootstrapperBase](http://caliburnmicro.com/documentation/bootstrapper) class from which you can inherit your own bootstrapper class. It has a virtual method `OnStartup` which you can override to do the initialization of your `shellview`. It also provides a utility method `DisplayRootViewFor` which can be used for displaying the related view for a specified `viewmodel` type.

So a simple implementation would look like this,

```
protected override void OnStartup(object sender, StartupEventArgs e)
{
    DisplayRootViewFor<TShellViewModel>();
}
```

where `TShellViewModel` is the type of your Shell ViewModel. Framework will resolve the view using convention and does the necessary groundwork to display the same. [This link](http://caliburnmicro.com/documentation/bootstrapper) will provide a broader picture for a `MEF` based IOC supported bootstrapper implementation for WPF.